# Gatsby.js - How to inject specific CSS/JS in head section of page in Gatsby.js

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am currently working on a Gatsby.js project.

Right now the page has a header component which consists of a burger menu component and navigation, as well as a footer component.

When viewing the site on chrome when selecting under performance tab **slow 3G** the burger menu does not toggle, which means the script for the burger menu is not inside the head component.

The styling is fine as I believe critical CSS is rendered inside HEAD by Gatsby.js automatically.

So, my question is, how can I inject critical CSS or JS from component/external files inside the head of the page.

Any advice/tips/help will be really appreciated, as I am kinder stuck on this.

Kind Regards,

Ronny

Comment: please share some code.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways how to put scripts and stylesheets into `<head>`s or `<body>`s is by using `gatsby-ssr.js`.

Inside `gatsby-ssr.js` (usually located in the project root) you can do something like this:

```
import React from "react";

export function onRenderBody({ setHeadComponents, setPreBodyComponents, setPostBodyComponents }) {

    // Add something into <head>
    setHeadComponents([
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_YOUR_URL_HERE_" />,
        <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html=`
            // plain javascript code here
        `
        }}
        />,
    ]);
    
    // Add something at the beginning of <body>
    setPreBodyComponents([
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_YOUR_URL_HERE_" />,
    ]);
    
    // Add something at the end of <body>
    setPostBodyComponents([
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_YOUR_URL_HERE_" />,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. That makes sense how we add external css/scripts to head section. What I am more interested in finding out is how Gatsby itself recognises to add CSS inline inside in the head section of the page. I'm not sure if critical scripts from /src/ directory are added by Gatsby in the head section of the page. Would be really helpful if you or someone else would be able to explain this. Much appreciated. Ronny

Comment: Good example, very helpful. Note that `__html=` should be `__html:`.